# Plotting certain values in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am a novice in R and Rshiny programming and i'm currently working on an app that does principal components analysis based on any database uploaded. I am looking for a way to make an interactive plot of the eigen values obtained in my PCA by row names. I made my reaserch a little bit on the internet and I found a way to obtain the plot thanks to ggplot, but it is a static plot if I want to change the number of eigen values to plot i would have to go to the server side code and do it manually which is not the goal of all my work.So to be specific, I'm looking for a way to make a reactive barplot of all my eigen values in function of my rownames (that are my components) and be able to choose the eigen values that I want to keep, if anyone could help me it would be great !

the function is named output$eigplot
the code that I have obtained so far looks like this :

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(d3heatmap)
library(DT)

shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "Spectrométrie",
  # Hea

  # Input in sidepanel:
  tabPanel(
    "Données",
    tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".well { max-width: 20em; }"),
    # Tags:
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "select[multiple] { width: 100%; height:10em}"),
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "select { width: 100%}"),
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "input { width: 19em; max-width:100%}")
    ),
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               selectInput(
                 "readFunction",
                 "Function to read data:",
                 c(
                   # Base R:
                   "read.table","read.csv","read.csv2","read.delim","read.delim2",
                   # foreign functions:
                   "read.spss","read.arff","read.dta","read.dbf","read.epiiinfo",
                   "read.mtp","read.octave","read.ssd","read.xport", "read.systat",
                   # Advanced functions:
                   "scan","readLines"
                 )
               )),
        column(4,
               htmlOutput("ArgSelect")),
        column(4,
               # Argument field:
               htmlOutput("ArgText"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(4, fileInput("file", "Upload data-file:")),
        # Variable selection:
        column(4, htmlOutput("varselect")),
        column(4, textInput("name", "Dataset name:", "Data"))    
      )  
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("table"))
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "ACP",
    fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
      12,
      p(
        "Visualisons quelques statistiques descriptives de nos variables :"
      )
    ))),
    mainPanel(
      fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
        12, dataTableOutput("table2", width = "100%")
      ))),
      fluidPage(fluidRow(
        column(6, p("La matrice de corrélations :")),
        d3heatmapOutput("heatmap", width = "100%", height =
                          "1000px")
      )),
      fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
        7, dataTableOutput("coord")
      ))),
      fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
        7, dataTableOutput("contrib")
      ))),
      fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
        7, dataTableOutput("cos2")
      ))),
      fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
        12, plotOutput("eigplot")
      ))),
      fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
        12, plotOutput("indivplot")
      )))
    )
  )
))
```

**Server**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    ### Argument names:
    ArgNames <- reactive({
        Names <- names(formals(input$readFunction)[-1])
        Names <- Names[Names!="..."]
        return(Names)
    })

    # Argument selector:
    output$ArgSelect <- renderUI({
        if (length(ArgNames())==0) return(NULL)

        selectInput("arg","Argument:",ArgNames())
    })

    ## Arg text field:
    output$ArgText <- renderUI({
        fun__arg <- paste0(input$readFunction,"__",input$arg)

        if (is.null(input$arg)) return(NULL)

        Defaults <- formals(input$readFunction)

        if (is.null(input[[fun__arg]]))
        {
            textInput(fun__arg, label = "Enter value:", value = deparse(Defaults[[input$arg]])) 
        } else {
            textInput(fun__arg, label = "Enter value:", value = input[[fun__arg]]) 
        }
    })


    ### Data import:
    Dataset <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$file)) {
            # User has not uploaded a file yet
            return(data.frame())
        }

        args <- grep(paste0("^",input$readFunction,"__"), names(input), value = TRUE)

        argList <- list()
        for (i in seq_along(args))
        {
            argList[[i]] <- eval(parse(text=input[[args[i]]]))
        }
        names(argList) <- gsub(paste0("^",input$readFunction,"__"),"",args)

        argList <- argList[names(argList) %in% ArgNames()]

        Dataset <- as.data.frame(do.call(input$readFunction,c(list(input$file$datapath),argList)))
        return(Dataset)
    })

    # Select variables:
    output$varselect <- renderUI({

        if (identical(Dataset(), '') || identical(Dataset(),data.frame())) return(NULL)

        # Variable selection:    
        selectInput("vars", "Variables to use:",
                    names(Dataset()), names(Dataset()), multiple =TRUE)            
    })

    # Show table:
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE], rownames = FALSE)
    })


    output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(

        datatable(summary( Dataset()[,input$vars]),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center')),
                                 pageLength = 6
                                 )
    ) 
    )

    output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        corr = cor(dat)
        return(d3heatmap(corr, scale="column"))
    }) 

    output$fprinc <-DT::renderDataTable({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        u = res.pca["eig"]
        u = as.data.frame(u)
        names(u)[c(1:3)]<-c("valeurs propres", "Pourcentage de la variance", "pourcentage cumulé de la variance")
        datatable(u)
    })

    output$eigplot <- renderPlot({ 
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        u = res.pca["eig"]
        u = as.data.frame(u)
        ggplot(u, aes(x=rownames(u), y=u[,2])) + 
            geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue", color="grey50") + coord_flip() +labs(y="Composantes", x = "% de la variance")
    })

    output$coord <-DT::renderDataTable({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        u = res.pca$var["coord"]
        u = as.data.frame(u)
        datatable(u)
    })

    output$contrib <-DT::renderDataTable({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        u = res.pca$var["contrib"]
        u = as.data.frame(u)
        datatable(u)
    })

    output$cos2 <-DT::renderDataTable({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        u = res.pca$var["cos2"]
        u = as.data.frame(u)
        datatable(u)
    })

    output$indivplot<-renderPlot({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        plot(res.pca, choix = "ind", autoLab = "yes")
    })

    output$cercle<-renderPlot({
        dat = Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]
        res.pca <- PCA(dat, graph = FALSE)
        plot(res.pca, choix = "var", autoLab = "yes")
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Your example is way too long and complicated: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to make a **minimal** reproducible example. Besides, I'm a little confused: why should your barplot depend on the rownames? Overall, here's my advice on what you should do: 1) use a toy dataset (```mtcars```, ```iris```...); 2) create the (static) plot you want with a code as little as possible; 3) implement this code in a shiny app to reproduce a **static** plot; 4) try making some of the components reactive

Comment: If you don't succeed after having done this, post the code necessary to reproduce the shiny app with the static plot and explain what components of the plot should be reactive. However, be sure to make the code in your post as little as possible. There's no need to have a big ```ui``` and a big ```server```, just what is necessary